# Tablesorter and Tablesorter Pager Column highlighting problem

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have a problem highlighting a column when using Tablesorter and Pager.
The column seems to highlight initially, but after using the pager then it goes wrong.

Here is the link:
http://www.moneycheckerpen.com/test/test-tablesorter.html

The problem:
Initially the column highlights correctly when the sortable headers are clicked.
The problem seems to occur after the table pager is used.  Then some cells in the column are highlighted and some some are not.  Some cells in the unclicked (header) columns become highlighted.

I have put an alert message to display the intended column (class td's) to be highlighted.  This displays correctly.  The column does highlight correctly before the alert message and then does not highlight properly immediately after it.

I wish the column to be simply highlighted when the corresponding (sortable) column header is clicked.

Many Thanks.

Comment: @Tomalak Meaning it highlights some cells in one column and other cells in another column.  Thank-you

Comment: Please edit into your question a proper, thorough comparison of what you expect to happen vs what does happen, along with a description of what debugging steps you have tried so far. SO is a Q&A, not a "fix my code for me" website.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just missing the css theme file, try adding this:

```
<link href="http://tablesorter.com/themes/blue/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And of course, point to your own stylesheet once you've confirmed this is the problem.